Expression short cut evaluation in Postgresql
In C, the classic short cut evalution might be something like
if ( a != NULL && a->b == 0 )...
to avoid evaluating a structure reference if invalid...
I'm trying something similar in a postgresql trigger:

IF TG_TABLE_NAME::text != 'collection_item' OR OLD.domain = 'HERB' OR NEW.domain = 'HERB' THEN
  ... blah
END IF;

So if the table is collection_item it contains the field domain, but other tables don't have that field. So in theory if table is not collection_item, it should short circuit and not evaluate OLD.domain. However this wasn't working, it would give an error that
`ERROR: record "old" has no field "domain"
So I read here about evaluation rules,
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL
It implies that if you encounter this problem you can get around it with CASE. So I tried that...
IF (CASE WHEN TG_TABLE_NAME::text != 'collection_item' THEN true WHEN OLD.domain = 'HERB' OR NEW.domain = 'HERB' THEN true ELSE false END) THEN
... blah
END IF;

but I still get ``ERROR: record "old" has no field "domain"`
I can get around it with nesting IFs...
IF  TG_TABLE_NAME::text = 'collection_item' THEN
    IF OLD.domain = 'HERB' OR NEW.domain = 'HERB' THEN
        is_target := true;
    END IF;
ELSE
    is_target := true;
END IF;

But I'm curious why my other attempts don't work.
I'm expecting short cut evalution to work.

Easiest workaround would be to use JSON. Trying to access a non-existing JSON attribute returns null but no exception is raised. So here it is - IF TG_TABLE_NAME::text != 'collection_item' OR (OLD::json ->> 'domain') = 'HERB' OR (NEW::json ->> 'domain') = 'HERB' THEN ...

I guess that's a cute little hack.

Well, rather a possibility to do some dynamic stuff in a strictly typed environment.

The expressions in PL/pgSQL are "compiled" before execution. The compilation is transformation from text form to AST form. In this form it is interpreted by expression executor. In your case, the compilation stage fails. It should be fully completed without dependency on result of any operator or expression.
The expression compilation is done immediately before first expression execution (evaluation) inside session.
PLpgSQL uses similar steps. Before first execution in the session, the source code is "compiled" to AST form. AST is stored to session cache, and interpreted. In this stage, the expressions are not compiled. Expressions are compiled just before own execution.

How can it be that the compilation stage fails when it can't know the type of the record until it is actually run? If the record is of type collection_item, the code runs fine. When the record is a different type, it fails. It can't know that at compile time.

The compilation of expressions are lazy - it is processed when trigger function is executed (and then all types are known), but before first own execution. Internally the PL/pgSQL expression is string - just string. When plpgsql should to evaluate an expression, then check if it was evaluated before (in session), and if yes, then use AST from dedicated cache. If not, then it is compiled to AST. Next step is evaluation of AST. You should to look on PLpgSQL statements and PLpgSQL expressions like on very different things - are "compiled" in different time and evaluated by different interpreters

That still does not compute. I can start a session, and create a record of a collection_item and it works, and according to you it is compiled and the "AST" is cached somewhere. Then I can create with a different table, in that session, and according to you it is run from compiled already in cache, and then crashes. Therefore, it's not crashing in compilation phase. Anyway... none of this actually explains why it actually crashes given that the language is dynamically typed, and supposedly has short circuit evaluation... certainly of case statements, says the documentation.

@ccthecc - there are other factors a) PLpgSQL can compile one function to independent trees - for example one trigger function used against different tables will have one AST for any table, b) when you do some changes in system catalogue, almost all system caches are invalidated, c) unfortunately some internals data about composite variables are not invalidated, and are used until end of session. Anyway - although PL/pgSQL is interpreted language, only few parts are dynamic.

@ccthecc - you can run experiment: prepare x(int) as select case $1 when 0 then 1 else 10/0 end; set plan_cache_mode to force_generic_plan ; execute x(0); , why result is ERROR:  division by zero?

That doesn't count because the documentation says constant expressions are a different situation. One can at least  understand that a compiler might pre-evaluate a constant expression, and the documentation lists that exception.

@ccthecc - no, it is same. You should to understand so there are more stages a) compilation plpgsql, execution plpgsql, compilation expression, execution expression. Reduced evaluation is done just in last stage, but your example fails on third stage that is not reduced. Try to read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html
